# Datepicker get date according to server date/time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to make work datepicker according to server time , how to set the server time to datepicker Jquery Ui, any help will be appreciated

Yes via clinet side we cannot get the server datetime, is there any procedure to get the server date/time and apply to date picker in PHP?

Comment: Get the difference in offset and use that client side? Or use the offset on the server to change it accordingly.

Comment: Hi jon thanks for response can you give me a example for same?

Comment: Both languages (PHP and JS) have a way to get the timezone.  So if you use the picker to choose just a date/time, send the timezone offset to PHP and use that with the DateTime object in PHP, or if dealing with just the numerical data, you can add/subtract as needed based on what the PHP timezone is set to.

Comment: jquery ui datepicker is an input field which creates a month/day/year input value. Why do you need the server datetime for this?

Comment: Yes, but I need at front end not at back end, i was saying if we get the time from back end and then how to apply in front end.

Comment: Hi bozdoz, I'm suing in line which generates the calender according to client browser, but i need accoding to timezone set in server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_date=date("d-m-Y"); ?>

<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="_date" value="<?=$_date;?>"/>
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In my case i have used folloing script. Hope it will help you!
    $('#selectedPicker').datepick
    ({
        yearRange: '1980:2010', 
        alignment: 'bottomRight',
        onSelect: updateSelected, 
        altField: '#set_Date', 
        showTrigger: '#calImg'
    }).datepick('setDate', '<?php echo $server_date; ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It will work and set maxDate if possible so the greater date is not selected

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#ppcertdate" ).datepicker({  maxDate: "<?=date("d/m/Y");?>", dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); 
    $("#ppcertdate").datepicker("option","defaultDate", "<?=date("d/m/Y");?>");
});
```